# How to write the sql query for this percentage query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the percentage in my database. My english is not good, so I'll show 2 pictures of what I want to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried. but hint, try using a windowed sum

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow. Images aren't helpful to the users you're asking help of when posting data. We can't use it as we can't copy and paste it into our environment; we'd have to transcript it. When posting data please take the time to post it as what it is `text`; specifically formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements.

Answer (score 0):

First get the total cost, in the second query we have calculate the cost and percentage based on Name.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name varchar(100),
    Cost int
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Kelly',100)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Tom',50)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Kelly',30)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Mike',40)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Peter',30)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Peter',10)

DECLARE @total int

SELECT @total = sum(Cost) FROM @tbl t

SELECT @total

SELECT Name, Cost = SUM(Cost), Percentage = Cast((SUM(Cost)/ (@total * 1.00)) *100.00 AS decimal(18,2)) FROM @tbl t
GROUP BY t.Name
```

**Output:**

`Name   Cost Percentage
Kelly   130 50.00
Mike    40  15.38
Peter   40  15.38
Tom     50  19.23`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(Cost) Cost,
    (SELECT sum(Cost) FROM data) TotCost,
    SUM(Cost) / (SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM data) Perc
FROM data
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Watch out for integer math. cast amount to decimal if it is an integer or you will get 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

You may try with the following:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
  [Name] varchar(50),
  [Cost] int
)
INSERT INTO #Table
   ([Name], [Cost])
VALUES
   ('Kelly', 100),
   ('Tom', 50),
   ('Kelly', 30),
   ('Mike', 40),
   ('Peter', 30),
   ('Peter', 10)
```

Approach, using only calculation:

```
SELECT 
   [Name], 
   CONVERT(numeric(10, 2), SUM([Cost])* 100.0 / (SELECT SUM([Cost]) FROM #Table)) AS Percentage
FROM #Table
GROUP BY [Name]
ORDER BY CONVERT(numeric(10, 2), SUM([Cost])* 100.0 / (SELECT SUM([Cost]) FROM #Table))
```

Output:

```
Name    Percentage
Kelly   50.00
Tom     19.23
Mike    15.38
Peter   15.38
```

With this calculation the total sum of percentage is not always 100, because of [rounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [implicit type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-and-explicit-conversion). Next statement solves this issue:

```
;WITH CalculatedCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        [Name], 
        SUM([Cost])* 100.0 / (SELECT SUM([Cost]) FROM #Table) AS Percentage,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Name] DESC) AS Rn
    FROM #Table
    GROUP BY [Name]
)
SELECT 
    [Name],
    CASE 
        WHEN Rn = 1 THEN CONVERT(int, [Percentage]) + (100 - SUM(CONVERT(int, [Percentage])) OVER ())
        ELSE CONVERT(int, [Percentage]) 
    END AS [Percentage]
FROM CalculatedCTE
ORDER BY [Name]
```

Output:

```
Name    Percentage
Kelly   50
Mike    15
Peter   15
Tom     20
```